# Java absolute path adds user.home property when adding quotes - Linux

Tags: java, linux, jvm, quotes, absolute-path

If I try to use a path that contains spaces in Linux I get FileNotFoundException, obviously. But if I try to add double/single quotes in the path as workaround, I get the same exception.

I was trying to check the reason and I found out that the generated absolute path **when using quotes** became: the **user.home** system property + specified path.

For example:

If I use this path:

```
/home/db2inst1/Desktop/testing - Development Environmet/64_dev/testing/logs
```

This is the absolute path I get when trying to use quotes:

```
/home/db2inst1/"/home/db2inst1/Desktop/testing - Development Environmet/64_dev/testing/logs"
```

I also tried to replace the spaces with **"\ "** instead of adding quotes, but it did not work.

I tried a lot of API's and it happens every time, made this code just for testing:

```
System.out.println("- regular path: ");
System.out.println(new File(path).getPath());
System.out.println(new File(path).getAbsolutePath());               
System.out.println("- quoted path: ");
System.out.println(new File(quotedPath).getPath());
System.out.println(new File(quotedPath).getAbsolutePath());
```

And this is the output:

```
- regular path: 
/home/db2inst1/Desktop/testing - Development Environmet/64_dev/testing/logs/testing.log
/home/db2inst1/Desktop/testing - Development Environmet/64_dev/testing/logs/testing.log
- absolute path: 
"/home/db2inst1/Desktop/testing - Development Environmet/64_dev/testing/logs/testing.log"
/home/db2inst1/"/home/db2inst1/Desktop/testing - Development Environmet/64_dev/testing/logs/testing.log"
```

Does anyone know why this is happening and how to make it work?

Comment: use a path where?  What function call/api.  Show us some code.

Comment: Show us the String literals you used if you did.

Comment: Your initial statement is not at all obvious: "If I try to use a path that contains spaces in Linux I get FileNotFoundException, obviously." It depends on the context in which you are doing this.

Comment: Sorry, guys. Edited my post with further info!

Answer (score 1):

From your description it seems that you are calling the [`File(java.lang.String pathname)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#File%28java.lang.String%29) constructor.

If so, the `String` used to represent your path should not use quotes.

Quotes are not considered as special characters in the *abstract pathname* definition, as described in the [`java.io.File`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) documentation.

> An abstract pathname has two components:
>
> 1. An optional system-dependent prefix string, such as a disk-drive specifier, "/" for the UNIX >root directory, or "\\" for a Microsoft Windows UNC pathname, and
> 2. A sequence of zero or more string names.

Since quotes are not special characters, they are considered part of a *name*.

Example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    File quotes = new File("\"C:\\myFolder\"");
    File noQuotes = new File("C:\\myFolder");

    System.out.println("Absolute path with quotes:" + quotes.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Absolute path without quotes:" + noQuotes.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Equal: " + quotes.equals(noQuotes));

    File empty = new File("");
    File emptyQuotes = new File("\"\"");

    System.out.println("Empty path with quotes:" + empty.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Empty path without quotes:"
            + emptyQuotes.getAbsolutePath());
    System.out.println("Equal: " + empty.equals(emptyQuotes));
}
```

will produce the following output when run in `C:\temp` on Windows:

```
Absolute path with quotes:C:\temp\"C:\myFolder"
Absolute path without quotes:C:\myFolder
Equal: false
Empty path with quotes:C:\temp
Empty path without quotes:C:\temp\""
Equal: false
```

Comment: that means java File does not understand names with quotes since in windows C:\myFolder and "C:\myFolder" should be the same folder

Answer (score 0):

In windows a file name without blanks and the same quoted should refer to the same file (or folder). For instance if we have a folder called c:\uni2 both command lines

```
   dir c:\uni2
   dir "c:\uni2"
```

should give the same result. But in java

```
  String rename;
  boolean ya;

  File f1 = new File ("C:/UNI2");    // given that exists and it is a directory
  ya = f1.exists();                  // true
  ya = f1.isFile();                  // false
  ya = f1.isDirectory();             // true
  rename = f1.getAbsolutePath();     // "C:\\UNI2"


  f1 = new File ("\"C:/UNI2\"");     // in windows this should be the same directory!!
  ya = f1.exists();                  // false
  ya = f1.isFile();                  // false
  ya = f1.isDirectory();             // false
  rename = f1.getAbsolutePath();     // "C:\tmp\"C:\UNI2""
```

which is not the expected behavior (even if it is documented).